# How to write array of strings into binary file?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, binary, fstream

I am sending array of 5 strings into a function that will write them into a binary file. My problem is how can I do that? How can I check the size of array if I am sending it by a pointer? I included `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`.

```
void my_func(string *array, int n)
{
ofstream my_file("file.bin", ios_base::binary);
if (!my_file)
{
    cout << "error" << endl;
    return;
}
my_file.write((char*)array, n*sizeof(string));
my_file.close();
}

void fun1()
{
string array[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "enter word " << i + 1 << ": ";
    getline(cin, array[i]);
}
my_func(array,5);
return;
}
```

So this works, but I use too many bytes for nothing, I want to take correct amount of bytes. Or if there is an easy way to do all this, I would be thankful. And please give me a school example, I am a student.

Output:

[image]

Comment: How is `string` defined?

Comment: @LogicStuff i will post a picture

Comment: You are writing the very implementation of `std::string` to the file instead of its contents.

Comment: It is not clear that `string` is `std::string`, Lingxi.   The OP hasn't given enough information to conclude that.

Comment: I edited the post  with more information @PeteBecker .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I overwrite my answer, because first version was written with some misunderstanding*

You can simply do it by this way.

```
void my_func(string *str_array, int n)
{
    ofstream my_file("file.bin", ios_base::binary);
    if (!my_file.is_open()) {
        cout << "error" << endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // If strings are null-terminated use +1 to separate them in file
        my_file.write(&str_array[i][0], str_array[i].length() + 1);
        // If strings aren't null-terminated write a null symbol after string
        // my_file.write("\0", 1);
    }
    my_file.close();
}
```

This one of common mistakes of beginners - `sizeof(pointer type)` expected it returns array size but pointer size will be returned.

Comment: Given that a purpose of writing a file is normally so it can be subsequently read in, this is problematical.    There is no way the reader can get length information in order to read.   Unless the single string is ALL that is written to the file.

Comment: @Peter, it may be `null-terminated` string.

Comment: @ComradeAndrew but I want to write an array of strings, not just one string

Comment: @Kira, oh, sorry. So `int n` is number of this strings?

Comment: @ComradeAndrew thx you very much, yes that is what i was expecting. Thanks.